# regex problem for newbie ranges of numbers

Tags: php, regex

I really should polish up on my regex but for now can anyone help with this...

```
((2,3,4,11,8),(5,44,67,78,32,22,111,234))
```

as you can see, each range of numbers is comma separated and, in this example, there are 2 ranges of of numbers.

In a live scenario there could be many numbers and a handful of ranges.

So... how do i extract something like this into a php nested array or something similar?

ANY help appreciated

Comment: Are they always nested at a depth of two?   So, a single range of one number would be `((1))` - and three ranges of numbers, each three long, would look like `((1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$input = str_replace(array('(', ')'), array('[', ']'), $input);
$output = json_decode($input);
```

This might work as well

Comment: Needs to be `$input = str_replace("(", "[", $input);` and `$input = str_replace(")", "]", $input);`

Comment: maybe it's even possible to get the input in json from the start

Comment: the storage format is arbitrary. how would a JSON string look? I think the first str_replace could be changed to preg_replace to accommodate arrays.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) wisely and do it like this:

```
$ranges = '((2,3,4,11,8),(5,44,67,78,32,22,111,234))';

//break into groups
$array = explode('),(', $ranges);

//trim any parenthesis left and then split by comma ,
foreach($array as &$group)
    $group = explode(',',trim($group, '()'));

//display result
var_dump($array);
```

**This outputs:**

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => string '2' (length=1)
      1 => string '3' (length=1)
      2 => string '4' (length=1)
      3 => string '11' (length=2)
      4 => string '8' (length=1)
  1 => &
    array
      0 => string '5' (length=1)
      1 => string '44' (length=2)
      2 => string '67' (length=2)
      3 => string '78' (length=2)
      4 => string '32' (length=2)
      5 => string '22' (length=2)
      6 => string '111' (length=3)
      7 => string '234' (length=3)
```